# Best way to resolve dependency order in Rails asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have a RoR app that uses lots of individual .less files to build my styles. I have one master .less file (config.less) that has variables that other files use. I can manually go through each of these child files and add `@import` statements, but I have quite a few, and this doesn't seem like the best way. Is there a standard way of setting a certain order if I'm using `*= require_tree .`?

I've tried to include require it above `require_tree` with

```
...
*= require 'less/config'
*= require_tree .
```

but I still get an error in a subsequent .less file complaining that it can't find a value in `config`

```
variable @base is undefined
  (in /Users/me/project/app/assets/stylesheets/less/mixins.less)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way is to **not** use `*= require_tree .` and to specify the imports/require lines individually.

From the **[Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives)**

> Directives are processed top to bottom, but **the order in which files are included by require_tree is unspecified. You should not rely on any particular order among those.** If you need to ensure some particular JavaScript ends up above some other in the concatenated file, require the prerequisite file first in the manifest. Note that the family of require directives prevents files from being included twice in the output.

Comment: Ok I buy that for sure. I ran into problems doing it that way because I included this tag in my main application layout: `<%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] %>`, then Heroku complained it couldn't find those particular files b/c they weren't precompiled.

Comment: That's a completely separate issue. By default rails only precompiles `application.js` and `application.css`.

Comment: Again, check out the **[Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets)**, specifically: `The default matcher for compiling files includes application.js, application.css and all non-JS/CSS files (this will include all image assets automatically):` You want to check out `config.assets.precompile` in your `config/application.rb`